# How to expand particular cell in MatTable to 100% of row height?

Tags: css, angular-material

For some reasons setting `height:100%` does not work. 
[image]

Any ideas on how to expand only given cell (the red one) to 100% of row height?

**Here is Stackblitz for you**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-927yqj?file=app/table-basic-example.css

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.mat-column-symbol{
  background-color:red;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
.mat-column-symbol{
    background-color:red;
    align-self: stretch;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: That works indeed. Any explanation on why height 100% does not work?

Comment: I think 'cause ".mat-header-row" and ".mat-row" have the rule "align-items: center" and not "stretch". So we have to change that property (align-self:stretch) and transform our cell in another flexbox and tell: 'Hey, now that you are finally stretch, let center my text!" (so we add "align-items: center)! :)

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/L4h2rwc1/ . Height attribute works here for some reasons

Comment: In your new example the parent have a fixed height so its child percentual height works. In the previus one, our row have only a padding with no height set so 'height:100%' doesn't work! This is the difference. If you put, for exemple, `.mat-header-row, .mat-row {height:100px}` your code works well.